# Python - Method is called more times than it should

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I am developing an application using PyQt. I have different push buttons that are connected to the method `subeventos`. 
When that method is called, it fetches data from a database (the data depends on the button clicked), organizes said data in a list and replaces several radio buttons' names with the string of each element from that list. Those radio buttons were created in Qt-Designer.

When a radio button is checked (toggled) it connects to the method `radio_clicked`.

The first time I start the app and check a radio button it calls the method `radio_clicked` once, as it should. After, if I select a different radio button, it now calls the method `radio_clicked` twice and it shouldn't. If I go back and select a different push button and select a random radio button it will call the method `radio_clicked` 4 times, and so on. This is not desirable, that method should always be called only once.

The code is below. Can you help me understand why this happens and how to avoid it? Thank you.

```
    def subeventos(self, evento):
        self.set_tab(4)

        subeventos=["NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL"] #lista nula
        query="SELECT subeventos from eventos_e_subeventos WHERE evento='"+evento+"';"
        cur.execute(query)
        subeventos_fetch=str(cur.fetchall()).strip("[(u',')]").decode('unicode-escape')
        subeventos_split=subeventos_fetch.split(",")

        for i, subevento in enumerate(subeventos_split):
            subeventos[i]=subevento


        for i,subevento in enumerate(subeventos): #Apresente o nome dos subeventos nos RadioButtons dinamicamente
            radiobutton="R"+str(i+1)
            if subevento=="NULL": #Se não exisitr subevento, não mostrar botão
                getattr(self, radiobutton).setVisible(False)
            else:
                getattr(self, radiobutton).setVisible(True)
                getattr(self, radiobutton).setText(subevento)
                getattr(self, radiobutton).toggled.connect(lambda: self.radio_clicked(evento))



    def radio_clicked(self, evento):
        print "I got here!"
        radiobutton=str(self.sender().objectName())
        subevento=getattr(self,radiobutton).text()
        self.BotaoConfirmarSubeventos.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_database(evento, subevento))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the radio_clicked calls coming from the same radiobutton? or different radiobuttons? The toggle.connect signal will trigger whenever it is switched on or off, not just on.  So if you have two radio buttons with one selected, when you click the other radio buttons, it will send two toggle.connect, one for radiobutton1 and one for radiobutton2, not just the one that has been checked.  If that is the problem, you can add

```
if self.radiobutton.isChecked():
    subevento=getattr(self,radiobutton).text()
    self.BotaoConfirmarSubeventos.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_database(evento, subevento))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I've this before and got the same results. To solve this, I replaced the QRadioButtons with QPushButtons in the method `subeventos` and connected them to the method `radio_clicked`. In the last method I also disconnected all of those buttons, so when the program gets to `subeventos`again, it will ´reconnect' to `radio_clicked` and the issue was solved.

Comment: Diogo why don't you post as an answer?